# Palindrome animation pausing at beginning and end

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I have created a nice animation using tikz and the animate package, which I am playing in palindrome form. It's something like the following example, although of course this is simpler than my real document. The problem is that I need it to *pause briefly* at the beginning and end of the animation, as if the first and last frames had a longer duration than the others. Is there a way to do this?

One idea I had was that rather than there being 11 frames with \rTheta going from 0 to 10, instead there could be 31 with \rTheta going from -10 to 20. Then there could be a conditional which sets a negative value of \rTheta to 0, and a value greater than 10 would be set to 10. This would give exactly the effect I want. Not sure if this is possible, or if there is a better way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,palindrome]{10}
\multiframe{11}{rTheta=0+.1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node (b) at (10,0) {b};
\node (c) at ($(0,0)!\rTheta!(10,0)$) {$X$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `timeline` option of the `animateinline` environment. From the specified file, you can describe when to use each frame of the `animateinline` environment, reorder or repeat some of them, or even change the frame rate several times.

Here are two ways to add the desired pauses. The second one should be a bit more efficient, because the `a` and `b` nodes are only drawn once, at the beginning.

## First way

```
\begin{filecontents*}{timeline.txt}
:1:0   % change framerate to 1 fps
:10:1  % change framerate to 10 fps
::2
::3
::4
::5
::6
::7
::8
::9
:1:10  % change framerate to 1 fps
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,palindrome,timeline=timeline.txt]{10}
\multiframe{11}{rTheta=0+.1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node (b) at (10,0) {b};
\node at ($(a)!\rTheta!(b)$) {$X$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Second way

```
\begin{filecontents*}{timeline2.txt}
:1:0x0,1  %  1 fps; use frame 0 as persistent background
:10:2     % 10 fps
::3
::4
::5
::6
::7
::8
::9
::10
:1:11     %  1 fps
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,palindrome,timeline=timeline2.txt]{10}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
    \node (b) at (10,0) {b};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %
  \newframe
  %
  \multiframe{11}{rTheta=0+.1}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path (a) -- (b);    % establish bounding box & size
      \node at ($(a)!\rTheta!(b)$) {$X$};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The command `\newframe` accepts an optional argument, which allows changing the frame rate in an animation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcommand\animframe[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base}]
    \path coordinate (a) at (0,0) coordinate (b) at (10,0); 
    \path[use as bounding box] node at (a) {\phantom{$X$}} node at (b) {\phantom{$X$}}; 
    \path node at (a) {a} node at (b) {b} node at ($(a)!#1!(b)$) {$X$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,palindrome]{1} % start with low frame rate
  \animframe{0.0}
\newframe[10] % higher frame rate for main part 
  \multiframe{9}{rTheta=0.1+.1}{\animframe{\rTheta}}
\newframe[1]  % end with low frame rate
  \animframe{1.0}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very elegant way, thanks!